# SSH Issue during Cloudera wizard step "Install Agent"

Tags: java, ssh, hbase, cloudera

I trying to install HBase on a servers A and B (Ubuntu 18.04)

For that I using CDM (CDM 6.3.1~1466458.ubuntu1804) installed on server A to handle installation of HBASE on a server A and B.

But I have a problem during the step "Install Agents", the wizard display the following error message "Exhausted available authentication methods".

I have found some post on the Cloudera forum which speak about NOPASSWD to add into the sudoers file of the server B, but in my case I have already  established a ssh connexion from the server A to the server B in command line and run a sudo command without any password, so I suppose my servers was correctly configured.

To be precise I trying to connect my servers by using a private key which I have generate a key couple in server A by using the following command :

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa
```

And after a add the content of the generated file `.ssh/id_rsa.pub` into the `.ssh/authorized_keys` file of server B  After a retry I obtain the same result.

I found this trace in the log file:

```
2020-01-02 09:48:39,559 WARN NodeConfiguratorThread-22-0:com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfigurator: Could not authenticate to SERVER_B net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Exhausted available authentication methods at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.auth(SSHClient.java:232) at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.auth(SSHClient.java:208) at com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfigurator.connect(NodeConfigurator.java:416) at com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfigurator.configure(NodeConfigurator.java:1028) at com.cloudera.server.cmf.node.NodeConfigurator.run(NodeConfigurator.java:1106) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthException: Problem getting public key from PKCS8KeyFile{resource=[PrivateKeyStringResource]} at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.KeyedAuthMethod.putPubKey(KeyedAuthMethod.java:46) at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AuthPublickey.buildReq(AuthPublickey.java:62) at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AuthPublickey.buildReq(AuthPublickey.java:81) at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.AbstractAuthMethod.request(AbstractAuthMethod.java:63) at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.UserAuthImpl.authenticate(UserAuthImpl.java:68) at net.schmizz.sshj.SSHClient.auth(SSHClient.java:226) ... 9 more

Caused by: java.io.IOException: unrecognised object: OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY at org.bouncycastle.openssl.PEMParser.readObject(Unknown Source) at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.keyprovider.PKCS8KeyFile.readKeyPair(PKCS8KeyFile.java:132) at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.keyprovider.PKCS8KeyFile.getPublic(PKCS8KeyFile.java:78) at net.schmizz.sshj.userauth.method.KeyedAuthMethod.putPubKey(KeyedAuthMethod.java:44)

... 14 more
```

Does anyone have an idea to help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found the origin of the problem. I need to add the pub key from server A on server B but I need also from server B to server A. That's all

Answer (score 2):

I hit this exact same issue, and it turns out `ssh-keygen` creates a private key file with `BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY` that the Java libraries Cloudera uses don't know how to parse. You can instead use `openssl` with a command like:

```
openssl genrsa -out mykey.pem 1024
```

Unlike `ssh-keygen` that won't give you the public key you need, and the builtin `openssl` commands to get a public key from a private key aren't in a format Cloudera accepts. For *that*, you *can* use `ssh-keygen` like so:

```
ssh-keygen -y -f mykey.pem > mykey.pub
```